# Could not connect Jdwp, trying to debug app on emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, visual-studio-2022, jdwp

I am using Visual Studio 2022 to create an android app that i am debugging in an emulator.
After updating Visual Studio(minor version update 17.9.4) i was unable to debug my application anymore.

The emulator starts fine, but then gives the error:
Waiting for debugger
Application XXX(xxx) is waiting for the debugger to attach.

In Visual Studio Debug output window it shows the following error:

```
warning: Could not connect Jdwp. Mono.AndroidTools.AdbException: cannot bind listener: cannot bind to 127.0.0.1:8100: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions. (10013)
   at Mono.AndroidTools.Util.AggregateAsyncResult.CheckError(CancellationToken token) in D:\a\_work\1\s\External\androidtools\Mono.AndroidTools\Util\AggregateAsyncResult.cs:line 72
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Xamarin.AndroidTools.Debugging.DebuggingExtensions.<ConnectJdwpAsync>d__7.MoveNext() in D:\a\_work\1\s\External\androidtools\Xamarin.AndroidTools\Debugging\DebuggingExtensions.cs:line 183
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Xamarin.AndroidTools.Debugging.DebuggingExtensions.<StartWithDebuggingAsync>d__1.MoveNext() in D:\a\_work\1\s\External\androidtools\Xamarin.AndroidTools\Debugging\DebuggingExtensions.cs:line 61
```

I have verified that the port 8100 is already used by the Windows system:

```
System  4   IPv4 unspecified    8100    TCP Not allowed, not restricted
```

My question is, if it is possible to change the port that Jdwp is using or there is another way to get around this problem.

I have of cause looked around and tried a few thing like:

- Creating new emulators
- adb root; adb reverse tcp:8080 tcp:8080
- restarted my machine
- Reinstalled Androide Emulator Hypervisor Driver and the Android Emulator tools

I have thought about using a real Android to debug my application, but are hoping, i don't have to resort to that. Also think that port 8100, still would be needed in that case.

At the moment i am unable to debug my application, so i am hoping that someone can help me out or point me in the right direction.